# KVM image size has changed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

We had a 180GB VM image. Inside the guest VM everything is OK and hdd size is 180G. but when we look the image size on the host it is 475MB. I am afraid that if we restart, the VM wouldn't work. I checked the size by

```
ls -sh 
457M x.img
```

and

```
qemu-img info x.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 456M (478309888 bytes)
disk size: 456M
```

this is the this configuration :

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/vm/x.img'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

and the disk cache setting is default.

both host and VM are ubuntu 12.04 server

---

this is the output of df and du on the VM

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2       183G  119G   56G  69% /
```

du:

```
119G    .
```

but strange thing is happening on the host, the output of df is:

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda3       1.4T  817G  492G  63% /vm
```

and the output of du on /vm is :

```
604G    .
```

Comment: what does `df` and `du` show inside the VM? How was the disk image created?

Comment: @dyasny I have edited the post. tnx.

Comment: are there any snapshots used? what exactly do you have under /vm ?

Answer (score 1):

The empty blocks are not count with -s option. You can test with `ls -lh` to see the complete size. And by default, there is a lot of empty blocks in a hard drive

You can restart your VM without risk (except you modify the disk manually)

In your VM, ask the disk usage : you should see arround 456M used

Comment: The same result, I am sure at least 100G isn't empty.